# Powershell Chrome close empty tab

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

Due to the fact that I have to boot up a lot of applications and a Chrome browser and I can't just autostart them because it all depends on which network I'm connected to, I'm writing a short PowerShell script. It's basically a bunch of invoke-items and then this thing

```
$urls = "my.intranet.com", "www.google.com", "www.microsoft.com"
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Foreach ($url in $urls)
{
    start $url
}
```

These aren't the actual URLs, but you get the picture.

Now, whenever I do this, I get one extra tab in Chrome. It's the default empty tab of Chrome. While not hugely annoying, it's pretty ugly.

How do I tell my Powershell to close an empty tab labelled "New Tab" in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of closing the empty tab, just start the browser with only the tabs you want.

To do this, pass the URLs as arguments to `chrome.exe`:

```
$urls = "my.intranet.com", "www.google.com", "www.microsoft.com"
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList $urls
```

*Edit: Adding opening in new window, as asked for in the comments*

If you want Chrome to a new window for the tabs, just specify the `--new-window` switch as well as the URLs, like so:

```
$arguments = "--new-window", "my.intranet.com", "www.google.com", "www.microsoft.com"
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments
```

Comment: An interesting approach. However, ideally I would open a new window as I'm using Chrome with some other tabs.

But this is perfectly functional, were I not so difficult.

Comment: @XQQ That's not a problem, just use the `--new-window` switch. I have updated the answer to include that version as well.